# Find register values after some MOV, XOR, RCL, and DIV instructions

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, masm

Please help me for this Assembly code. I need to find the values of `AX`, `BX` and `DX`, but I can not do this. I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
MOV AX,0d
RCL AX,1h
MOV AX,e213h 
MOV BX,d123h
XOR AX,BX
XOR BX,AX
XOR AX,BX
RCL AX,10h    ; Give AX=   BX=

MOV AX,215h
MOV DX,2h
MOV BX,8h
DIV BX    ; Give AX=   BX=   DX=

INT 20h
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question does not seem clear, however I try to answer. If you want to know the values of the registers you have at least two ways: the first involves executing the code on paper, which I suppose this exercise is for. The latter, involves creating the procedure as inline assembly in MASM or C.

Since, it seems to me an assignment, just do it on paper:

```
; ax=?, bx=?, dx=? this is the starting point. assume all registers are unknown
MOV AX,0d
; ax=0, bx=?, dx=? mov performs copy between registers, 0d is 0 (in decimal)
RCL AX,1h
; ... and so on... If you don't known where to look, have a look at for RCL: https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_273.html
MOV AX,0e213h 
MOV BX,0d123h
XOR AX,BX
XOR BX,AX
XOR AX,BX
RCL AX,10h    ; here1 Give AX=   BX=

MOV AX,0215h
MOV DX,2h
MOV BX,8h
DIV BX    ; here2 Give AX=   BX=   DX=

INT 20h
```

[Here](http://ref.x86asm.net/) you can browse all the opcodes and mnemonics.

Comment: Thank you very much. I could not figure out RCL. Does RCL rotate according to decimal or hexadecimal value? RCL AX,10h  means it will shift to left 16 times, or 10 times?

Comment: h stands for hexadecimal, therefore 10h is 16.